# How Does Javascript if statement indentation work?

Tags: javascript

How many spaces should be used for each line of if statement at the beginning of the line?
suppose we have 10 lines of nested if statements, what is the formula to determine how many lines to be used? Also can a programmer use the tab key instead to obtain proper indentation for a statement.

```
if (a !== 0) {
 if (b > 1) {
  if (c < 1) {
```

Comment: Depends on what style you use. Doesn't make a difference anyways

Comment: There is no requirement for any type of indentation, it's all personal preference. Of course you can use tabs. I'm also curious as to why you would ever have 10 nested ifs?

Comment: *"How Does Javascript if statement indentation work?"* It doesn't. White spaces are ignored in JavaScript. You could write everything on a single line if you wanted to.

Comment: Choose a style and apply it everywhere.

Comment: at least 1 space - otherwise you haven't got any indentation - like too many questions on SO :D

Comment: you could also put them all in one line. it's a purely aesthetic choice. voting to close this as opinion-based before the old tabs-vs-spaces-debate flares up.

Answer (score 2):

Indentations and spaces is not a requirement it just helps your code to be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike languages like Python in which whitespace is considered semantic by the compiler, the Javascript compiler ignores runs of whitespace altogether. In my experience, though, the most common indentation (tab) lengths are 2 spaces and 4. My personal preference is 4, but plenty of other people will say 2.

I will say, though, that if you're using more than 4, you're either going to need to break your more nested logic up into multiple lines, or you're going to end up with a lot of overruns -- even with only 4 spaces, I often find myself running over 80 characters.